# empty and zero as a string

Tags: php

How do I write an if condition that will evaluate a zero as not empty? I'm writing a validation script and if the field is blank, I throw an error. In the case of a select with numerical values that start with 0 (zero), that should not considered to be empty. The manual states that a string 0 is considered to be empty and returns false. If I change empty to !isset, the zero works but the other textboxes that are truly empty pass validation. How do I write this to handle my case?

Comment: Why not do a string comparison first? `$test == "0"` ?

Comment: `if($value !== 0 )`, because `(false == 0)` is true. but `false === 0` is not true

Comment: The *length* of the string "0" is... (that is, ask PHP a different question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (strlen($x)) {
  // win \o/ (not empty)
}
```

Happy coding.

(All text box / form input content is inherently just text. Any meaning as a numerical value comes later and each representation can be validated. 0 is coerced back to "0" in `strlen`.)

Comment: @pst.. I just tried strlen but a zero is being reported as "0" length. It shouldn't though right?

Comment: @jim See http://codepad.viper-7.com/6hVirM -- "works here". Perhaps there really is *no* 0?

Comment: Ok, thanks for that my friend.. I have to have an issue somewhere else. Thanks for the help and the pointer of asking a different question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [is_null()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)?

```
if (is_null($value) || $value === "") {}

if (empty($value) && $value !== 0)
```

Comment: Charles.. What I get with is_null is the exact same behavior that !isset gives me. Empty inputs now pass validation when they shouldn't

Comment: Charles, here is what I get with is_null: `string(5) "aaaaa"
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(4) "2222"
string(5) "test1"
string(0) ""
string(1) "2"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!is_numeric($var) && empty($var))
{
    // empty
}
else
{
    // not empty
}
```